# How fast should I expect to load data on a high performance computer?

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-tuning

I am considering a model where I use PostgreSQL COPY to copy data from a file into a table. I was wondering what kind of performance to expect on high-end hardware. An interval in MB/s would be nice so I can start estimating. If you just know the answer on other databases, I would be interested to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit hard to tell, what is high-end hardware?

Using Oracle on EMC storage 60MB/s is certainly possible.
Using that same old Oracle on exadata can be slightly faster, 300MB/s and sometimes higher, again, depending on the configuration. A full rack is faster than a half rack ...

Answer (score 1):

@David, you are almost certainly going to be IO bound on your database server, with the following (commonly understood) caveats:

1. If your target for the `COPY` uses `FUNCTION`s or `TRIGGER`s or `FOREIGN KEY`s, expect slower performance
2. If you have already created `INDEX`es before you `COPY` your data, the data will be added to the `INDEX`, which will slow things down.

The fastest way to `COPY` load data in to PostgreSQL is via `COPY` in to a table that has no `INDEX`es and has `fsync = off`, and `checkpoint_segments = 50` (or at least some value that isn't the default of 3) in `postgresql.conf`. I prefer the following strategy:

1. `BEGIN`
2. `DROP INDEX my_tbl_idx;
3. `COPY` ...
4. `CREATE INDEX` my_tbl_idx ON my_tbl
5. `COMMIT`
6. `ANALYZE my_tbl`

I explicitly add the `ANALYZE` after the `COMMIT` because I don't typically want to wait for `pg_autovacuum` to start.

Comment: While `fsync = off` can speed up the load indeed, it is **highly** recommended to turn it on again after the data has been loaded to avoid data corruption.

Comment: Absolutely. `synchronous_commit = off` is the preferred & recommended way of getting the speed benefits of `fsync = off` without sacrificing the integrity of your database.